# How to get Header of First page of word document

Tags: c#

I want a First page header of word document.

In my project I have used the Inter-op object for getting the header but in a some document I get other 2nd page header and after that i got first page header because document having header footer properties like even-odd header-footer, firstpagedifferent etc.

Example:

I want this below output:

First page header - Header page 1

Second page header - Header page 2
but I got this below output because of header and footer firstpagedifferent property:

Second page header - Header page 1

First page header - Header page 2

```
StringBuilder strBldrHeader = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder strBldrFooter = new StringBuilder();

foreach (Word.Section section in document.Sections)
{
    foreach (Word.HeaderFooter header in section.Headers)
    {
        Word.Range rangeHeader = header.Range;
        string txtHeader = rangeHeader.Text.Trim().Replace("/", "");
        if (txtHeader == null || txtHeader.ToString().Trim().Length <= 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        strBldrHeader.AppendLine(txtHeader.Trim());             
    }
    foreach (Word.HeaderFooter footer in section.Footers)
    {
        Word.Range rangeFooter = footer.Range;
        string txtFooter = rangeFooter.Text.Trim().Replace("/", "");
        if (txtFooter == null || txtFooter.ToString().Trim().Length <= 0)
        {
            continue;
        }
        strBldrFooter.AppendLine(txtFooter.Trim());
    }
}
```

Note: I have also used OpenXML SDK but there is same scenario that output is not showing in a proper order.

Regards, 
Tejasvita

Comment: It looks like you are not using the [Open XML SDK for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx), right? If you will be processing Office 2007 and later documents, you might find this SDK much easier to use. It is also designed for server work, so it doesn't need Office to be installed (and doesn't run Office itself, as the Interop object does).

Comment: I have also tried with  Open XML SDK but there is same issue with openXML is't not showing header text in proper order due to header's property.

Comment: If you get the same results, then I would start by sticking with Open XML SDK, because once you solve this issue, it will give you much better performance (and one less Office license to buy).